# Android: getLocationOnScreen returns 0 for imageview inside gridview

Tags: android, gridview

When first physical clicking on an item, the getLocationOnScreen returns 0, but on following clicks it returns the right location. 
However, when calling gridView.performItemClick the location always returns 0.
Any idea how to resolve this?

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            int[] location = new int[2];
            image.getLocationOnScreen(location);
```

Comment: Also need help on this.